# Different website open every time search in google

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Whenever i search any thing on google it takes me to a different website instead of google search.

I tried all three browsers installed on my computer.
Google Chrome
Firefox
Internet Explorer

They are doing same and taking me to https://cjurl.site

I have uninstalled and reinstalled my browsers but no success.

Comment: Can you check that your Host file doesn't have google.com in it? Your Host file is located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts (you can open it with Notepad)

Comment: whether this behavior only happened in google site? Try to search something using Bing site, whether it redirect to "https://cjurl.site"?

Comment: It does the same with bing.com as well

Comment: Have you ever installed something related cjurl, try to check the system installs programs. Besides, perhaps your computer contains some virus, please try to detect it.